# Finding the Orthonormal Basis of a given Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

[image]

Hi, So I am not sure how to do this problem.

I think what I have to do is find a basis for the space of 2x2 matrices that are orthogonal to the identity matrix s.t. the HS inner product. And from there find an orthonormal basis. But I am not sure how to find the initial basis with the given information?

Thanks

Comment: find a basis of $V$ and then apply Gram Schmidt if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the initial basis simple note that
$$
V = \{ A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \colon \mathrm{tr} (A) = 0 \}.
$$

So your space has dimension 3, and a basis is formed by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

However this is not orthogonal, but from here can you proceed?

Comment: Yes thank you very much! @Hugo